Bellman equation matrix form for Q-function
It's rather easy to write construct the matrices for the matrix form of the Bellman equation for the V-function (they are everywhere on the internet) but I can't find the equivalent version for the Q-function. The only one I found is from the LSTD paper, but I don't understand how to construct the matrix $\Pi_{\pi}$. Usually, $\Pi$ has shape $|S| \times |A|$, but $\Pi_{\pi}$ has shape $|S| \times |S||A|$. What exactly is it?
Is there any other source of information on this?


I found the answer in this paper


As far as I understand it, the policy $\Pi$ is a map of a state to an action when in that state. If the action and state space are both discrete with $N$ available actions and $M$ available states then using the labels $s = 1,2,3, ... M$ for state and $a = 1,2,3, ... N$ for action and write the components of $Q^\pi$ out in the form of $Q_{sa}$
$$ Q^\pi = \left ( \begin{matrix}Q_{11}\\ Q_{12}\\ ...\\ Q_{1N}\\ Q_{21}\\ Q_{22}\\ ...\\ Q_{2N}\\ ...\\ Q_{M1}\\ Q_{M2}\\ ...\\ Q_{MN}\\ \end{matrix} \right ) 
$$
then a non-deterministic policy with probability of $p_{sa}$ to apply an action $a$ when in state $s$ could be written as
$$
\Pi = \left ( 
\begin{matrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & \ldots & p_{1N} & 0      & 0      & \ldots & 0      & 0 & 0 & 0  & \ldots & \ldots \cr
0      & 0      & \ldots & 0      & p_{21} & p_{22} & \ldots & p_{2N} & 0 & 0 & 0  & \ldots & \ldots \cr  
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 0      & 0      & 0      & \ldots & 0      & p_{31} & p_{32} & \ldots \cr
\vdots \cr
\vdots \cr
0      & 0      & 0      & 0      & 0      & 0      & \ldots & 0      & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & p_{M1} & p_{M2} & \ldots & p_{MN} \cr 
\end{matrix} 
\right ) 
$$
where $\Sigma_a p_{sa} = 1$. The $\Pi$ is a sort of $(1 \times N)$-block diagonal matrix.
